# onDraw() method is called every time when i changed or swipe page in view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ondraw

I have custom view in one of fragment of view pager. and problem is when i swipe view pager , onDraw() method is called every time. can anyone suggest me how to stop calling onDraw() once its already drawn.?

More Detail :

I have a customView  class name pie chart which takes data and draw pie chart for me and which is called in fragment. and dynamically add to the layout. In the very first time it works fine and draw pie chart smoothly. but on swipe or page change pie chart repeatedly drawn which cause flickering effect.

Comment: its not a problem that onDraw is called when swiping, othervise you would not see your pages at all

Comment: @pskink i have added my scenario. everything works fine except onDraw() of custom view is called on page change evrytime

Comment: so you need to optimize your onDraw method

Answer (score 0):

I have encounterd the same problem.I used hardware acceleration to prevent drawing repeatedly.Maybe below code is helpful to you.

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    //...

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        MyView view = new MyView(context);
        container.addView(view);
        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        return view;
    }

    //...
}
```